# Query Gorm GOolang Join Table

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
type Packages struct {
   ID              uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
   PackageName     string    `json:"package_name" gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
   Version         []Version `json:"version" gorm:"foreignkey:PackageID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Version struct {
   ID                 uint           `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
   CreatedAt          time.Time      `json:"created_at" gorm:"autoCreateTime"`
   UpdatedAt          time.Time      `json:"updated_at" gorm:"autoUpdateTime"`
   PackageID          uint           `json:"-"`
   VersionCode        string         `json:"version_code" gorm:"type:varchar(100);uniqueIndex:idx_uniq"`
   BuildNumber        int            `json:"build_number"`
}
```

I need a Query to select all the package(full details needed including the fields in version struct) based on versioncode condition.

This query is giving result against the database:

SELECT * FROM packages  JOIN versions ON packages.id=versions.package_id WHERE versions.version_code=1.0

but when I changed into GORM:

```
config.DB.Select("*").Joins("LEFT JOIN versions ON packages.id=versions.package_id AND versions.version_code=?", version_code).Find(&packages)
```

it is not filtering based on version code, it is still giving full details.
ANYONE PLEASE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To load the `Version` slice inside the `Packages` struct, use the [Preload](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#content-inner) function. Your query should look like this:

```
var packages []Packages
err := config.DB.Preload("Version").Joins("LEFT JOIN versions ON packages.id=versions.package_id").Where("versions.version_code=?", version_code).Find(&packages).Error
```